# HighCharts Editor Plugin Example not working

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-editor

So I have the jquery-simple-rest plugin for Highcharts, (same used in the example documentation). I've linked the js file, and am not getting any errors in my browser. The documentation mentions also needing to the highed.use.

```
//The installer
highed.plugins.editor.install("jquery-simple-rest",{

//Contains information about the plugin - optional
meta:{
    version:"1.0.0",
    author:"Highsoft",
    homepage:"https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-editor/plugins/jquery-simple-rest.js"
},

//Add additional external dependencies here
dependencies:[
    "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"
],

//This is the prototype options which the plugin accepts
options:{
    url:{
        required:!0,
        type:"string"}
},

//Called when the chart changes
chartchange:function(e,t)
{jQuery.ajax({
    url:t.url,
    data:e.json,
    dataType:"json",
    type:"post"
    ,success:function(){
        highed.snackBar("CHART SAVED")
    },
    error:function(e,t){
        highed.snackBar("unable to save chart: "+t)
    }
   })
  }
});


highed.plugins.editor.use('jquery-simple-rest', {options:{
    url:{
        required:!0,
        type:"string"}
    },
  }
);
```

I can not get this plugin to appear in my the editor, and have no idea what it is I'm doing wrong.

link to example: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-editor/wiki/Plugins

Comment: The editor is still in a beta version so I guess the best option to do is contacting directly with editor's authors - you can contact them on github https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-editor/issues